# .htaccess RewriteRule : not all rules work on Ionos

Tags: .htaccess

I'm deploying my local web site (mamp server) in my shared hosting (ionos).
In local, the web site work.

In my public directory, i have two files : index.php (client) and admin.php (admin).

I used Rewrite Engine in .htaccess to rewrite my URLs.
All the URLs for client work but not for admin (just the first -> admin/dashboard)

Here .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^post$                                              public/index.php?p=post [L,nc]
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]*)$                                     index.php?p=post&id=$1 [L,nc]
RewriteRule ^login$                                             index.php?p=login [L,nc]
RewriteRule ^logout$                                            index.php?p=logout [L,nc]
RewriteRule ^register$                                          index.php?p=register [L,nc]
RewriteRule ^forgot-password$                                   index.php?p=forgot-password [L,nc]
RewriteRule ^reset-password/(.*)/(.*)$                          index.php?p=reset-password&email=$1&token=$2 [L,nc]
RewriteRule ^reset-password$                                    index.php?p=reset-password [L,nc]
RewriteRule ^contact$                                           index.php?p=contact [L,nc]
RewriteRule ^validate/(.*)/(.*)$                                index.php?p=validate&email=$1&token=$2 [L,nc]
RewriteRule ^admin/dashboard$                                   admin.php?p=dashboard [L,nc]
RewriteRule ^admin/post/new$                                    admin.php?p=post-new [L,nc]
RewriteRule ^admin/post/confirm-delete/([0-9]*)$                admin.php?p=post-confirm-delete&id=$1 [L,nc]
RewriteRule ^admin/post/delete/([0-9]*)$                        admin.php?p=post-delete&id=$1 [L,nc]
RewriteRule ^admin/post/update/([0-9]*)$                        admin.php?p=post-update&id=$1 [L,nc]
RewriteRule ^admin/post/([0-9]*)$                               admin.php?p=post&id=$1 [L,nc]
RewriteRule ^admin/comment$                                     admin.php?p=comment [L,nc]
RewriteRule ^admin/comment/confirm-approve/([0-9]*)$            admin.php?p=comment-confirm-approve&id=$1 [L,nc]
RewriteRule ^admin/comment/approve/([0-9]*)$                    admin.php?p=comment-approve&id=$1 [L,nc]
RewriteRule ^admin/comment/confirm-delete/([0-9]*)$             admin.php?p=comment-confirm-delete&id=$1 [L,nc]
RewriteRule ^admin/comment/delete/([0-9]*)$                     admin.php?p=comment-delete&id=$1 [L,nc]
RewriteRule ^admin/user$                                        admin.php?p=user [L,nc]
RewriteRule ^admin/user/confirm-validate/([0-9]*)$              admin.php?p=user-confirm-validate&id=$1 [L,nc]
RewriteRule ^admin/user/validate/([0-9]*)$                      admin.php?p=user-validate&id=$1 [L,nc]
RewriteRule ^admin/user/update/([0-9]*)$                        admin.php?p=user-update&id=$1 [L,nc]
RewriteRule ^admin/user/confirm-delete/([0-9]*)$                admin.php?p=user-confirm-delete&id=$1 [L,nc]
RewriteRule ^admin/user/delete/([0-9]*)$                        admin.php?p=user-delete&id=$1 [L,nc]
```

> For example :
> admin/post/new --> call admin.php but without p=post-new.
> If I call directly admin.php?p=post-new, it's work

> In localhost -> I have the Query String
> 'p' => string 'post-new' (length=8)
> But in production, nothing in $_GET

Can you help me please ?

Comment: The rules seems correct. I usually have [L,nc] (last, no case) as flags. Maybe you have a redirect in code for the admin section, and your admin url changes somehow.

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for sharing your efforts. Could you please do also add for what sample URLs its not working? Thank you.

Comment: Could you please confirm if you are hitting link `http://localhost:80/admin/post/new` in browser and its not sending query string to `admin.php` file in backend while getting rewrite request? Please confirm on same once.

Comment: Try to disable `MultiViews` - that is often the culprit in situations like this, where you have such a partial overlap between the "fake" URL, and an actually physically existing file

Comment: This is certainly a MultiViews issue because `/admin/post/new` will be rewritten to `/admin.php/post/new` (without any parameters) - before the mod_rewrite rule is processed.

Comment: I add `Options -Multiviews` in .htaccess and it solves my problems--> thank you so much guys !